# How to use front and back camera at the same time?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, surfaceview

I want to use both front and back cameras at the same time. I have used two surface views. I have tried to implement the code in following answer.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24238301/6874315

The problem is that the camera API is now deprecated and the code was too old. I tried using the Camera 2 API in the same way but the camera instance won't open and i get a blank white screen.
I get the following two errors:

**Camera 0 not available! java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service**

**Camera 1 not available! java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service**

What i wanna do is capture picture from front and back camera simultaneously on a button click. But i'm not able to open both front and back cameras at the same time.
Is there anything that I do to use both cameras at same time?

Comment: I've been looking for years, and I've yet to get my hands on a device that supports this. The Samsung Galaxy S4 can do it, but apparently only with an OEM app.

Comment: There must be someother way. I was thinking that if i could not get the camera preview from both front and back may be i could click a picture in a fraction of second for switching the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444841/11338123

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075569/11338123

I think it is possible in some devices and it is impossible in others

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that it is possible to use both cameras simultaneously. But, you could switching between two cameras like in [this sample](https://github.com/botyourbusiness/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hzitoun/camera2SecretPictureTaker/services/PictureCapturingServiceImpl.java) for short time interval.

Also you can modify you program to process camera images in the background thread in [such way](https://books.google.ru/books?id=iy50DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=backgroundThread.start();%20backgroundHandler%20%3D%20new%20Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());&source=bl&ots=Tn_CIIPjZ0&sig=ACfU3U1HxSKbo1yr16fVcQ3a4IAa_bf__w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxu5rnp8ToAhWDw4sKHesxCXEQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=backgroundThread.start()%3B%20backgroundHandler%20%3D%20new%20Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper())%3B&f=false) to avoid GUI freezing.

So, you may try to make a little changes in the sample to get front and back camera instances for testing your idea. Good luck!

Comment: Well, there are some mobile phones capable of using both cameras. Maybe that is because they have separate hardware. But it is possible as I have seen it in Samsung Galaxy S4